# How to fetch Article Titles from a Wordpress Website and Store them in an Array?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am creating an Android App for my Website.(for ex: fossbytes android app).

I want to fetch all the Article properties like Title, Publish Date, Tags, and category of each article and store them in a Array.

For Ex: An Array containing all the Article Titles
        Another Array containing all the Article Category
        and so on

I am somewhat familiar with sqlite and totally unfamiliar with fetching data from servers and stuff like that.

My website is Running on Wordpress. I have tables in it that contain all these informations. How can i accomplish this.

I can not try anything as i know nothing about fetching data from server database tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see how client-server interacts using REST APIs. Check if Wordpress provide APIs to access the data stored in the sql tables. If they do, you can hit the APIs from your Android app, and use the response, you receive from the API server, to show on the UI as you want. That is the basic approach.

There are plenty of libraries available to help you do network operations hassle free, like Retrofit + GSON. You might have to do network operations in the background, so could look into building background services in Android.

You can read this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html), it might help you.